# OwnerDraw on compact framework controls

Tags: winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

is there way (unmanaged maybe?) how to do the ownerdraw functionality on ListBox/ListView/TreeView controls in Compact Framework? Or is there some another controls (free? paid?) with similar functionaly (kinetic scroll for example)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's far from straightforward to do owner or custom drawing int he CF.  Christian Helle has [an example for the ListView in his blog here](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-custom-drawing-in-netcf.html).

Answer (score 1):

1) I filed a [request](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=466623) to Microsoft to add this feature.

2) You can do this using the [ListBox2](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/a204d759-9829-3b16-2d24-1ab2282c0c1c.htm) class in the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx)

3) You can derive from ListControl and add this logic yourself (I did this by looking at the source code of the .NET Framework Version of ListBox)

Comment: 2) This class looks goog, but don't support kinetic scroll, which I need. 3) I'll try it with combination with article posted by @ctacke. Thanks